# Different result at the same file (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

i have this script , that take IP Address and ping them , and then it save the result to TXT file or EXCEL file.

and the issue is that - >  If i will change the name output name file and even change the IP address from the original ( or new ) file i will get in the end file with all the previous test connections.

**The Script :**

```
$IPs = Get-Content "C:\IPs.txt"

foreach($name in $Ips){
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name is up" -ForegroundColor Green
    $output+="$name is up,"+"`n"
    }
    else{
Write-Host "$name is down" -ForegroundColor Red
$output+="$name is down,"+"`n"

        }
}
$output | Out-File "C:\IP_Result"
```

**TXT file with the IP Address :**

```
8.8.8.8
192.168.33.2
10.10.10.10
192.168.33.4
1.1.1.1
```

so when i run the script for the first time i receive :

```
8.8.8.8 is up,
192.168.33.2 is up,
10.10.10.10 is down,
192.168.33.4 is up,
1.1.1.1 is up,
```

now if i will change the `$output | Out-File` to another file name ( so i can get new file with results )
i will receive new file name but will the previous results

for example

New IP Address ( inserted in new file with new name in `$IPs = Get-Content` )

```
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

now i run the script and the result :

```
8.8.8.8 is up,
192.168.33.2 is up,
10.10.10.10 is down,
192.168.33.4 is up,
1.1.1.1 is up,
1.1.1.1 is up,
2.2.2.2 is down,
3.3.3.3 is down,
4.4.4.4 is down,
```

**why i see the old results ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same variable `$output` and keep appending to it (`$output +=`). If you ran the script in a completly new window, you would get single results.
To prevent that behavior initiate the variable `$output` in the beginning of the script:

```
$output = $null # = empty
```

or

```
$output = @() # = array
```

or

```
$output = "" # = string
```

Another way would be to remove the variable when you are done using it:

```
Remove-Variable output
```

Here is an additional tipp:
Using `+=` will recreate the collection with every iteration. For a few dozen values thats ok but for multiple hundred it's much faster to collect the output of the foreach itself:

```
$output = foreach($name in $Ips){
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
        Write-Host "$name is up" -ForegroundColor Green
        "$name is up,"
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "$name is down" -ForegroundColor Red
        "$name is down,"
    }
}
```

And you wont have to reinitiate the variable by yourself.

Comment: @Simba made a little addition I had no time for.